# How do I compose strings for later serial transmission?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I really don't know how to phrase this question well, and this is my first post on stackoverflow, so my apologies in advance.

This is all on a Cyclone IV FPGA.

First off, I have a module called UART connected to two physical pins, TX and RX.  UART works beautifully, with parameterized transmission rates, stop bits, parity, etc.

Around that UART module is a controller module that includes two FIFOs, one for outgoing and one for incoming data.  It's called UART_System and includes helper ports that for sending and receiving data:

```
input clock,
input [7:0] tx_data,
input tx_req,
output tx_buffer_full,
output [7:0] rx_data,
input rx_req,
output rx_buffer_empty
```

When rx_buffer_empty is low, you assert rx_req for one clock, and read the data off rx_data. A similar method is done for transmission.  This doesn't send data over the wire yet, it just interacts with the FIFOs, which the UART later pulls from and transmits with a slower clock.  The FIFOs are dual clock Quartus IP.  This all works fine.

I'm still a novice with Verilog...So how do I queue an entire message in one clock cycle? Obviously, you can't, so this is what I've come up with.

First, some storage:

```
    byte response_message [0:127];
    reg [6:0] response_message_start;
    reg [6:0] response_message_end;
```

On reset, `response_message_start` and `response_message_end` is set to 0.  On every clock cycle,

```
always @(negedge clock) 
...
    // Check for outgoing data
    if(response_message_start != response_message_end) begin
        tx_req <= 'b1;
        tx_data <= response_message[response_message_start];
        response_message_start <= response_message_start + 1;
    end else begin
        tx_req <= 'b0;
        response_message_start <= 0;
        response_message_end <= 0;
    end
...
end
```

(Ignore the fact that it doesn't handle tx_buffer_full gracefully right now).   The above works well, I believe.

This is my problem.  Suppose there's some user event where I want to transmit a message, like "Button1 was pressed!", I have:

```
always (negedge clock) begin
...
    if(~button0) begin
        response_message[response_message_end+0] <= "B";
        response_message[response_message_end+1] <= "u";
        response_message[response_message_end+2] <= "t";
        response_message[response_message_end+3] <= "t";
        response_message[response_message_end+4] <= "o";
        response_message[response_message_end+5] <= "n";
        response_message[response_message_end+6] <= " ";
        response_message[response_message_end+7] <= "0";
        response_message[response_message_end+8] <= "!";
        response_message[response_message_end+9] <= "\n";
        response_message_end <= response_message_end + 10;
    end
    if(~button1) begin
        response_message[response_message_end+0] <= "B";
        response_message[response_message_end+1] <= "u";
        response_message[response_message_end+2] <= "t";
        response_message[response_message_end+3] <= "t";
        response_message[response_message_end+4] <= "o";
        response_message[response_message_end+5] <= "n";
        response_message[response_message_end+6] <= " ";
        response_message[response_message_end+7] <= "1";
        response_message[response_message_end+8] <= "!";
        response_message[response_message_end+9] <= "\n";
        response_message_end <= response_message_end + 10;
    end
...
end
```

But the above is using massive amounts of logic elements! Almost 70% of all LEs ("LC Combinationals") are coming from this module.  And not to mention that assigning one character at a time is horrendous programming style...  I have a strong background in other programming languages, but Verilog is starting to challenge me.

1. How can I copy prepared "strings" into a buffer later to be sent over a serial interface?
2. What's the best way to store several of these strings?  Internal Block ROM and clock out bytes from it into a buffer?  Constants, localparams?
3. And clearly if both button0 and button1 are pressed the result is going to be unpredictable! This makes me think that "<=" is not the correct assignment for this situation.

Please help!! Cheers

Comment: I guess those `+` consume the most logic resource. And I wonder if it will eliminate those additions if we use a packed, long string `reg [8 * 128 - 1:0] response_message` instead of the current FIFO structure.

Comment: Without having done a lot of research yet, I'm eyeing the additions as the main culprit for the logic elements.  Still need a way to queue multiple strings in a single clock cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the additions you can use a long packed string, as was suggested by @Light and use a shift operator on the whole string, something like the following.

```
    reg [8 * 128 - 1:0] response_message, tmp;
    ...
    always @(negedge clk) begin
        response_message <=  response_message | ("Button 0!\n" << (response_message_end * 8));
        ...
```

in addition make sure that you assign 'start'/'end' values in a single always block to avoid multiple drivers.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion. I'll try it later and if it works out I'll come back and update.

Comment: Looks like this is the most convenient solution.  Takes some work managing the end pointers, but shifting in the whole string is a workable solution.